# function overloading in interfaces differ in generics

Tags: function, kotlin

I have an interface and which has otherwise method which sends the respective Throwable object to the lambda (handler).

Because of the nature of lambda it does not accept any of the object(inherited ones) except the explicit type specified.

So i had to create another function which supplies the respective error to the handler and when there's is no handler just suppress those Throwables.

```
fun <T: Throwable> otherwise(onRejected: (T) -> Any?): MyInterface<Any>

fun otherwise(onRejected: (Throwable) -> Any?): MyInterface<Any>
```

But even tho one uses generic and another just takes Throwable, the compiler complaints that `The following declarations have the same JVM signature`.

I'd like to make a default handler and a primary handler which has a generic to pass only the Throwable they ask.

Any help would be appreciated :^).

Comment: A bit of context would help us guide you towards the right approach to work around your issue. What exactly is your problem when you keep only the generic function?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that both methods would have the same underlying signature after compilation. That's because concept of generics exists only at compile time – if you check the bytecode there's no `T`.

Both versions of `otherwise` take a lambda, which is compiled to `Function1` – an interface that makes use of generics, which get erased in bytecode – and since information about generics gets erased in bytecode you will have the following:

`fun otherwise(onRejected: (Throwable) -> Any?): MyInterface<Any>` is compiled to:

```
public static final MyInterface otherwise(@NotNull Function1 onRejected)
```

`fun <T: Throwable> otherwise(onRejected: (T) -> Any?): MyInterface<Any>` is compiled to:

```
public static final MyInterface otherwise(@NotNull Function1 onRejected)
```

Hence, the compilation error if you try having both in the same class.

Comment: But that does not answer _I'd like to make a default handler and a primary handler which has a generic to pass only the Throwable they ask_ :-(

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not sure I understood your issue, then. Could you provide an example to describe more in details what you'd like to achieve?